# column not found in laravel, when i want to update existing data

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I feel too difficult when trying to fix this. I want to update my existing data. Here's my laravel code:

```
public function updateakun()
    {
        $user = User::leftjoin('sosmeds', 'users.id', 'sosmeds.user_id')->find(request('id'));
        $user->name = request('nama');
        $user->email = request('email');
        $user->username = request('username');
        $user->bio = request('bio');
        $user->ig = request('ig');
        $user->update();

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => $user,
        ]);
    }
```

but, I got an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ig' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `ig` = tess, `users`.`updated_at` = 2021-05-26 12:10:22 where `id` is null)

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Might be a stupid question but does `ig` exist in `users` database table?

Comment: ig already joined with users, ig include with sosmeds table, see

Comment: That's not, how it works. With `$user->ig` you're trying to update a user. Did you setup an eloquent relationship in the `User` model to the `Sosmeds` model?

Comment: not yet i think, but thanks for your answer.. i think just join the table is solving the problem

Comment: Feel free to post your solution so that others with similar problems can find it